# Можно ли закруглить углы у outline?

Tags: html, css, border

Собственно, в этом и вопрос. У border есть border-radius. У outline такого свойства нет (вернее, для FF есть -moz-outline-radius, но в других браузерах такое не работает).

```css
div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   border-radius: 20px;
   outline: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-outline-radius

Comment: Как округлить outline я не знаю, но думаю что нельзя.
Можно использовать box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px green.

Comment: @МузыкаСергей, с box-shadow каждый может )) Я думал, вдруг есть какое-то лайфхак с outline'м

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=outline-radius иногда помогает узнать можно или нет

Comment: @Shnur, этот ресурс помогает узнать, будет ли работать определённое свойство в том или ином браузере. Как закруглить углы у outline там не написано, увы

Answer (score 1):

Напишите в `div` `outline: none`, т.е. отмените его вообще, и задайте в `div` `:focus` c необходимым бордером и его радиусом.

Comment: Вы можете скопировать сниппет из вопроса и показать с ним, как это работает.

Comment: Я так понял, что вам нужно убрать  квадратный outline к примеру у button, который появляется при клике на нее, в таком случае, я предлагаю просто убрать outline:none; и вместо него прописать :focus с border-radius

Comment: .button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline:none;                                                                                                 
 }   .button:focus{
        border:2px solid green;
        border-radius: 20px;

    }